# How to use GDB to analyse stack trace leading to system libraries?

Tags: gdb, segmentation-fault, stack-trace

I'm trying to find the reason for a segfault which is occurring on the level of system libraries.
I would like get some hints on how to use gdb to examine args of the `getenv()` call seen in the following stack trace.

As the trace shows - `getenv()` is not called directly by my code - call is nested in the chain of system calls initiated in my code. Call is starting with my routine `a_logmsg()` trying to get thread-safe `localtime - localtime_r()`, and `getenv()` is called later somewhere within the code of libc. OS is Solaris 8/SPARC.

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0xfed3c9a0 in getenv () from /usr/lib/libc.so.1
(gdb) where
#0  0xfed3c9a0 in getenv () from /usr/lib/libc.so.1
#1  0xfed46ab0 in getsystemTZ () from /usr/lib/libc.so.1
#2  0xfed44918 in ltzset_u () from /usr/lib/libc.so.1
#3  0xfed44140 in localtime_r () from /usr/lib/libc.so.1
#4  0x00029c28 in a_logmsg (fmt=0xfd5d0 "%s: no changes to config.") at misc.c:155
#5  0x000273b8 in a_sync_device (device_group=0x11e3ed0 "none", hostname=0xfbbffe8d "router",
    config_by=0xfbbffc8f "scheduled_archiving", platform=0x11e3ee0 "cisco", authset=0x11e3ef0 "set01",
    arch_method=0xffffcfc8 <Address 0xffffcfc8 out of bounds>) at arch.c:256
#6  0x00027ce8 in a_archive_single (arg=0x1606f50) at arch.c:498
#7  0xfe775378 in _lwp_start () from /usr/lib/libthread.so.1
#8  0xfe775378 in _lwp_start () from /usr/lib/libthread.so.1
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

Comment: Note that `getsystemTZ()` simply calls `getenv("TZ")` (plus some more stuff after that), which is _highly_ unlikely to be the cause of a segmentation fault of its own. As it with issues of memory corruption, the true culprit is usually somewhere else, in code execute before the place where you observe the crash. You should check your own code first. In this case the `a_*`-functions, at least.

Comment: Hi, thanks for remark about `getsystemTZ()`. As i wrote below in response to Employed Russian - direct cause of segfault seems to be corruption of `environ` variable which `getenv()` is trying to access, and it indeed looks like some memory problem caused by my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like get some hints on how to use gdb to examine args of the getenv() call seen in the following stack trace.

1. The source for Solaris libc is available [here](https://hg.java.net/hg/solaris~on-src/file/tip/usr/src/lib/libbc/libc/gen/common/getenv.c).
2. You can examine argument to `getenv` by setting the breakpoint on it, and looking at the registers. You'll need to know the [ABI](http://www.sics.se/~psm/sparcstack.html) that is used, but it's quite simple -- the argument to `getenv` is in register `i0`, and `print (char*)$i0` at the `(gdb)` prompt should print `"TZ"`.

Finally, the most likely reason for a crash in `getenv` is that you've corrupted the environment earlier. In particular, note that this code is *bad*:

```
void buggy()
{
   char buf[80];
   strcpy(buf, "FOO=BAR");
   putenv(buf);  // <-- BUG!
}
```

You could usually examine the environment via one of these commands:

```
(gdb) x/100s __environ
(gdb) x/100s environ
```

Chances are, you'll see strings there which do not contain the `=` sign.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your insight. i0 register indeed contains "TZ" which is without doubt argument for `getenv()` call. `x/100s environ` returns "address out of bounds", so it looks like `environ` variable became somehow corrupted, and `getenv()` is simply trying to access nonexistent address causing segfault. In fact it looks like some memory corruption caused by my code - i'll have to look at it more closely.